# Could some help to check which package I am missing?

Tags: packages

The compiler is showing "undefined control sequence" error, which is 100% reproducible [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbrcmcffsgbz).

I googled the error message, and the results imply that the error is caused by forgetting to load a package.

I've checked my code over and over again and didn't find a clue.

```
\documentclass{ximera}

\author{Jane Doe}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{My first section}

\begin{example}
\xi_n = [x_1 \dots x_n]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Could some help to check which package I am missing?

## error message

> Undefined control sequence.
>
> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
>
> \theabstract
>
> l.7 \maketitle
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: You are using a customized class file `ximera.cls`, and couldn't able to give suggestion without seeing that, off topic, please don't use `mathptmx`, instead of that use `newtxmath`

Comment: `\dots` is defined in `amsmath`

Comment: Can you post the `error` message which is stored in `.log` file for easy understanding?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I've changed `mathptmx` to `newtxmath`, didn't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added this line `\usepackage{amsmath}` just now, is it right?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I've pasted the error log just now.

Comment: @whnlp Hope the error belongs in your `class` file only, but not sure how to fix it without seeing the `class` file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the code by using your link.

As @MadyYuvi mentioned, You are using a customized class `ximera`, changing it article would fix the "undefined control sequence" error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Jane Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{My first section}

\begin{example}
\xi_n = [x_1 \dots x_n]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Two remarks here. 1- If the OP's problem is related to a specific class it generally means he cannot avoid to use it, as you propose. In that way you answer actually does not answer the question. 2- When you post an answer, make it a compilable example, which is not the case at the moment, due to (at least) the missing `title` definition.